# use Jetpack Compose ModalBottomSheet: The offset was read before being initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using `ModalBottomSheet` and have `State hoisting` to its ancestor components.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
      Demo4Theme {
        // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
          ArticleScreen()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
@Stable
class ArticleState(
  val orderModalState: SageSheetState,
  val filterModalState: DrawerState
)

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun rememberSageSheetState(
  state: SageSheetState = SageSheetState(
    coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope(), sheetState = rememberSheetState()
  )): SageSheetState {
  return remember { state }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun rememberArticleState(
  orderModalState: SageSheetState = rememberSageSheetState(),
  filterModalState: DrawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
): ArticleState {

  return remember {
    ArticleState(
      orderModalState = orderModalState,
      filterModalState = filterModalState
    )
  }
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ArticleScreen(
  state: ArticleState = rememberArticleState()
) {

  Column {
    Text("${state.orderModalState.sheetState.currentValue}")
    Text("${state.orderModalState.sheetState.isVisible}")
    Text("${state.orderModalState.sheetState.targetValue}")
    Button(onClick = { state.orderModalState.showModal() }) {
      Text("Show Modal")
    }
  }
  Modal(
    modalState = state.orderModalState,
  )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
class SageSheetState(
  private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
  val sheetState: SheetState,
  openBottomSheet: Boolean = false
) {
  var openBottomSheet by mutableStateOf(openBottomSheet)

  fun showModal() {
    coroutineScope.launch {
      openBottomSheet = true
      sheetState.collapse()
    }
  }

  fun closeModal() {
    coroutineScope.launch {
      sheetState.hide()
      openBottomSheet = false
    }
  }
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Modal(
  modalState: SageSheetState
) {

// Sheet content
  if (modalState.openBottomSheet) {
    ModalBottomSheet(
      onDismissRequest = { modalState.closeModal() },
      sheetState = modalState.sheetState,
    ) {
      Text("Hello")
    }
  }
}
```

But when I click on the `Show Modal` button, it goes wrong.

```
The offset was read before being initialized. Did you access the offset in a phase before layout, like effects or composition?
```

I don't know where I did wrong, maybe use `State hoisting` in wrong way, the official example is working fine(state save in itself).

You can view the full code [here](https://github.com/SageJustus/question/blob/main/demo4/app/src/main/java/com/sage/MainActivity.kt) and the full error message [here](https://github.com/SageJustus/question/blob/main/demo4/error.log).

###### Notice

> 1. I am using the latest version of Compose Material3 `androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha06`
> 2. You may need to modify repository settings if you want to run the project.

Comment: Fixed in `Compose Material 1.5.0-alpha01`. Link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/266780234

Comment: @SageJustus not sure if it helps but it seems to be resolved in `androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha08`. I have not checked if any other previous alpha release resolves this issue as well, but this version resolves it.

Comment: @ilkeraslan The higher version fixes this problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a DisposableEffect to ensure that the showModal and closeModal functions are called only after the layout phase.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
class SageSheetState(
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    val sheetState: SheetState,
    openBottomSheet: Boolean = false
) {
    var openBottomSheet by mutableStateOf(openBottomSheet)
        private set

    fun showModal() {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            openBottomSheet = true
            sheetState.collapse()
        }
    }

    fun closeModal() {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            sheetState.hide()
            openBottomSheet = false
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Modal(
    modalState: SageSheetState
) {
    DisposableEffect(modalState.openBottomSheet) {
        onDispose { }
    }

    // Sheet content
    if (modalState.openBottomSheet) {
        ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = { modalState.closeModal() },
            sheetState = modalState.sheetState,
        ) {
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I failed to run it successfully, did you succeed?